# Error al actualizar Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Es mi primera vez en este foro y necesito su ayuda. Hace unos días que no puedo actualizar el sistema Ubuntu Desktop. Soy nuevo en usar sistemas basados en Linux. Utilizo la versión 23.10 de Ubuntu.

Concretamente, este es el error que tengo:

```
sudo apt-get update -y 

Obj:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security InRelease              

Obj:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic InRelease                        

Obj:3 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                

Obj:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates InRelease                

Obj:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-backports InRelease

Ign:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/codeblocks-devs/release/ubuntu mantic InRelease

Obj:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/serge-rider/dbeaver-ce/ubuntu mantic InRelease

Err:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/codeblocks-devs/release/ubuntu mantic Release

  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.80 443]

Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
```

E: El repositorio «https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/codeblocks-devs/release/ubuntu mantic
Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.

> No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está
> deshabilitado por omisión.

> Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.

Comment: No se si esta pregunta tiene que estar aquí, pero como comentario, prueba a cambiar todos los http por https

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer esto:

```
sudo apt-get update || true
```

Agregar `|| true` al comando garantizará el éxito y permitirá que el script continúe incluso si la actualización falla.

También te recomiendo utilizar versiones LTS de Ubuntu, suelen ser mas estables.

Comment: Te agradezco mucho!!

Answer (score 0):

Hola la causa de esto es porque el repo de CodeBlocks no soporta la version 23.10. El proyecto anda abandonado la mejor alternativa es que aprendas como usar el compilador `g++` y utilizes C++ con `vscode`.
Para solucionar tu problema de la forma mas comoda, te brindo pasos:

1. Abre el ubuntu dash y escribe "software y actualizaciones"
2. Selecciona la pestaña de "Otro software"
3. Ahora selecciona **todos los ppa que digan codeblocks**
4. Finalmente selecciona "Eliminar"

[image: ppa]

Si te pregunta para recargar, dale que si y con eso deberia estar solucionado tu problema.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Egon!

Comment: @user351695 de nada, porfavor marca la respuesta con un check verde si te ayudo a resolver tu problema como se indica [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)